# overlapping CAShapeLayer outline

Tags: iphone, ios, cgpath, outline, cashapelayer

I have a 3D lookalike graphic object made of several CAShapeLayers. All the shapes (both ceiling and walls) has to be stroked. Some of the shapes share an edge - that seems to be the root of the problem.

However it seems that the outline is being drawn around an existing outline of another shape.
So I got those ugly pikes around some shapes.

How to get rid of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the lineJoin and lineCap property, Setting it to kCALineJoinRound and kCALineCapRound might help you.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer

Comment: Excellent! kCALineJoinRound and kCALineCapRound did the thing. Thank you so much!